# how setup lookup_field?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

AssertionError: Expected view blabla to be called with a URL keyword argument named "pk". Fix your URL conf, or set the `.lookup_field` attribute on the view correctly.

# If you want to use object lookups other than pk, set 'lookup_field'

well I don't want use URL to set pk , I want use pk from query_params for example something like :

```
request.query_params.get('id', None)
```

so how setup lookup_field ?

**SOLVED** 
it is on update method that we can override pk value

```
class blabla(generics.CreateAPIView,
            generics.ListAPIView,
            generics.RetrieveAPIView,
            generics.UpdateAPIView):

   def update(self, request, pk = None):
        log.debug("update pk= %s , data = %s" % (pk, str(request.data)))
        pk = request.data.get('id')
        self.kwargs['pk'] = request.data.get('id')
        return super().update(request, pk)
```

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38461366/multiple-lookup-fields-for-django-rest-framework

Answer (score 3):

Your code doesn't work because you reference to `request` object on class level, and it is doesn't exists: it is created on instance-level. But you don't need it at all, just make:
`lookup_field = 'id'`