# DRF how to return list filtered by lookup w/ custom router and modelviewset

Tags: django-rest-framework

I tried to search for answers as much as I can but I still don't know how to achieve my goal here.

My goal:
I need two api endpoints, one returns a list filtered by a lookup fields, and another returns an obj filtered by another field, both using GET method. For example:

`<ip>/api/books/bycategory/{category_lookup}/` This endpoint will return a list of books filtered by a category

`<ip>/api/books/byid/{id_lookup}/` This returns one book matches the specified id (not pk)

Since there's no built-in router that suits my needs here because the built-in ones don't provide url pattern with lookup that returns a list, so I figured I need to have a custom router of my own, so here's what I have:

```py
class CustomRouter(routers.SimpleRouter):
    routes = [
        routers.DynamicRoute(
            url=r'^{prefix}/{url_path}/{lookup}{trailing_slash}$',
            name='{basename}-{url_name}',
            detail=True,
            initkwargs={}
        )
    ]

router = CustomRouter()
router.register('books', BookViewSet)
```

and my serializer:

```py
class BookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = BookKeeper
        fields = '__all__'
```

Right until here I think I'm on the right track, but when it comes to the view, thats where i can't quite figure out. Right now I only have this incomplete viewset:

```py
class BookViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    queryset = BookKeeper.objects.all()
    serializer_class = BookSerializer

    @action(detail=True)
    def bycategory(self, request):
        lookup_field = 'category'

    @action(detail=True)
    def byid(self, request):
        lookup_field = 'id'
```

My first question here is I "think" `{url_path}` in the router url matches the method name with `@action` specified in the viewset somehow and that how they are connected, am I correct?

Second question is how do I use {lookup} value in the view?

Third, what's the `lookup_field` for if I'm to use like:

```py
def bycategory(self, request):
    return Response(BookKeeper.objects.filter(category=<lookup_value>))
```

Lastly what should my viewset be like anyway?

Any input will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Second question is how do I use {lookup} value in the view?

You need two lookup_fields for the same set. You can do that by a custom Mixin class. But in four case, it is better not to use routers but custom urls, so edit like this:

```py
# views.py
class BookViewSet(viewsets.ReadOnlyModelViewSet):
    queryset = BookKeeper.objects.all()
    serializer_class = BookSerializer

    @action(detail=True)
    def bycategory(self, request, category):
        # do filtering by category
        print(category)

    @action(detail=True)
    def byid(self, request, book_id):
        # do filtering by book_id
        print(book_id)
```

```py
# urls.py
get_by_id = views.BookViewSet.as_view(
    {
        'get': 'byid'
    }
)
get_by_category = views.BookViewSet.as_view(
    {
        'get': 'bycategory'
    }
)
urlpatterns += [
    url(
        r'^api/books/byid/(?P<book_id>[0-9a-f-]+)/',
        get_by_id,
        name='get-by-id'
    ),url(
        r'^api/books/bycategory/(?P<category>[0-9a-f-]+)/',
        get_by_category,
        name='get-by-category'
    )
]
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, i wanted to use router because I need similar endpoints for my other models too, so there will be many url to add and the patterns are mostly the same.

Comment: There is a similar question about that case. Check the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38462137/4665915