# Django endpoint with slug and id

Tags: python, django, endpoint

How to create endpoint that will return data using two different fields?

Model:

```py
class Post(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    post_title = models.CharField(max_length = 125)
    text = models.TextField()
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, unique=True, blank=True)
```

Serializer:

```py
class PostSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = [
            'id',
            'post_title',
            'text',
            'slug',
         ]
         lookup_field = 'slug'
```

View:

```py
class PostViewSet(mixins.ListModelMixin,
                   mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
                   mixins.UpdateModelMixin,
                   viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    queryset = Post.objects.all().order_by('id')
    serializer_class = PostSerializer
    ordering = ['id']
    lookup_field = 'slug'
```

Urls:

```py
router = routers.DefaultRouter()

router.register(r'post', PostViewSet)
urlpatterns = [
    path(r'', include(router.urls)),
]
```

Now my endpoints works only for slugs my question is what should I modify to use endpoints like:

```
localhost:9000/post/f18e8017-ebbc-432d-b1c6-1ff23737a744
```

and

```
localhost:9000/post/post-title
```

Comment: Technically, UUID is a valid slug so it's a bit ambiguous. But you can override the `retrieve` method to accommodate your needs

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiple lookup\_fields for django rest framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38461366/multiple-lookup-fields-for-django-rest-framework)