# 'ListSerializer' object is not callable Request Method

Tags: python, json, django, api, django-rest-framework

Unfortunately I'm facing the same problem as mentioned in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37578159/listserializer-object-is-not-callable). But it didn't solve the problem in my case.

My model:

```
class AppointmentCategory(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='General')
```

My Serializer:

```
class AppointmentCategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = AppointmentCategory
        fields = ('id', 'name',)
```

My View:

```
class AppointmentCategoryViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = AppointmentCategory.objects.all()
    serializer_class = AppointmentCategorySerializer(many=True)
```

I'm passing the post data in this format:

```
 [
  {
    "name": "Emergency"
  },
  {
    "name": "General"   
  }
 ]
```

It does work when I send only one element. However the above mentioned list fails to create two objects in the database. The error says:

```
'ListSerializer' object is not callable
```

I'm not sure how to solve this. Any ideas?

Comment: The very best way to solve this is to override the `def create(self, request):` method of your `AppointmentCategoryViewSet` if you want to pass a list of dictionaries.

Comment: Ya, I ended up doing that.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be instantiating the serialiser in the viewset definition. Just do:

```
serializer_class = AppointmentCategorySerializer
```

Note, this is exactly the same solution as recommended in the question you linked to.

Comment: That gives me the following error: {"non_field_errors":["Invalid data. Expected a dictionary, but got list."]}

Comment: @HasanIqbalAnik of course it wont work since the serialzier is expecting a post data of a dictionary form and you are trying to pass a list of dictionary which is obviously wont work