# Original exception text was: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'weight'

Tags: django-rest-framework

I got an Exception
*Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `weight` on serializer `WeightHistorySerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `QuerySet` instance.
Original exception text was: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'weight'.*
 When I tried to retrive data.

models.py

```
class WeightHistory(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    weight = models.FloatField(null=False, blank=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

serializers.py

```
class WeightHistorySerializer(serializers. HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:        
        model = WeightHistory        
        fields = (
            'id', 
            'weight',
            'user_id',
            'created_at'
        )   
        read_only_fields = ('id',)
```

views.py

```
def weight_history_detail(request, user_id):
    # Retrieve, update or delete a weight_history/detail.
    try:
        weight_history = WeightHistory.objects.filter(user_id=user_id)
    except WeightHistory.DoesNotExist:
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

    if request.method == 'GET':
        serializer = WeightHistorySerializer(weight_history)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

If it change to

```
weight_history = WeightHistory.objects.get(user_id=user_id)
```

It returns only one row, But I want all the rows with given user_id. So, What should I do to get all list with given user_id.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'weight'.
```

Yes. `QuerySet` is a `Set`, a list of objects.

```
<QuerySet [<Object1>, <Object2>,..]>
```

And that list has no attribute `weight`. Instead, the objects inside the `QuerySet` has the attribute `weight`.

```
weight_history = WeightHistory.objects.filter(user_id=user_id)
```

`filter` returns a `QuerySet`, a list of `WeightHistory` objects with `user_id=user_id`.

And you are trying to serialize the list as a single object.

Instead of this:

```
serializer = WeightHistorySerializer(weight_history)
```

Do this:

```
serializer = WeightHistorySerializer(weight_history, many=True)
```

`many=True` tells the serializer that a list of objects being passed for serialization.

Moreover,

```
try:
   weight_history = WeightHistory.objects.filter(user_id=user_id)
except WeightHistory.DoesNotExist:
   return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
```

This doesn't throw an exception at all. `filter` returns an empty QuerySet if no objects exist. `<QuerySet []>`.

So the final code is:

```
def weight_history_detail(request, user_id):
    # Retrieve, update or delete a weight_history/detail.
    weight_history = WeightHistory.objects.filter(user_id=user_id)
    if weight_history.count()<1:
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

    if request.method == 'GET':
        serializer = WeightHistorySerializer(weight_history, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Comment: Very Very Thank You Bro. It helped me. Keep in touch I need more help. Since, I am  a beginner in the Django rest framework

Comment: I have some issue. How Can I connect you? can you give me your email?

Answer (score 0):

> views.py

```
def weight_history_detail(request, user_id):
    # Retrieve, update or delete a weight_history/detail.
    try:
        weight_history = WeightHistory.objects.get(user_id=user_id) #get
        except WeightHistory.DoesNotExist:
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

    if request.method == 'GET':
        serializer = WeightHistorySerializer(weight_history)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

use `get` instead of `filter` it will solve you error